# today widget icon not display

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios8-today-widget

After I delete my app without removing the today widget in the Today area of Notification Center, I rerun the app, the today widget is there but without the icon. I could make it display after remove it and add it again or relaunch my iPhone. Is that a bug of iOS?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have all of your icons included in Xcode, it sounds like a bug with iOS. Apps installed from Xcode sometimes install differently than apps installed from the App Store. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove app when widget is enable.
2.Install your app again.
3.In Some iOS Version has a higher risk of  widget icon is gone.

Do test in different Version
It is ok：  iOS 8.0.2、iOS 9.0 and later

Has Problem version:  iOS 8.4.1、 iOS 8.3
(maybe in 8.1.1 ~ 8.4.1 has problem)